# Apache incorrect url rewrite for non-existent symlink files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory (`foo/uploads`), which contains 1 file: `file1.txt`

I have created a symlink to this directory (`bar/uploads`)

Here is my `.htaccess` file inside `bar`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And this is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bar

    <Directory /var/www/bar>
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I'm having is, if I try to access a non-existent file when using the symlinked folder, it is not producing a 404 response. Here is what I mean:

1. `foo.com/uploads/file1.txt` -> file served (CORRECT)
2. `foo.com/uploads/file2.txt` -> Apache 404 `ErrorDocument` served (CORRECT)
3. `bar.com/uploads/file1.txt` -> file served (CORRECT)
4. `bar.com/uploads/file2.txt` -> proceeds to `index.php` (INCORRECT)

I have also tried including:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`

Before the `RewriteRule`, but that doesn't make a difference.

Anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the front-controller to apply when accessed via `bar.com` then you could check the requested `Host` header in the rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Or, exclude the `/uploads` subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^uploads/ index.php [L]
```

Or, include another `.htaccess` file in the `/uploads` subdirectory that overrides the parent front-controller pattern. You can do this simply by disabling (or *enabling* - providing mod_rewrite inheritance is not enabled) the rewrite engine in the subdirectory:

```
# /uploads/.htaccess
RewriteEngine Off
```

Alternatively, disable `.htaccess` overrides altogether and move these directives to the  `<Directory /var/www/bar>` container inside the `bar.com` vHost.